# regex needed for a url pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in the process of adding some simplistic routing without using any particular framework.

current regex -->

```
/^(\w)\/?(\w)\/?(\w)\/?(\d+)$/g
```

The possible url pattern are

```
settings                                // should be matched to --> group1 = settings, group2 = null, group3 = null, group4 = null
settings/                               // should be matched to --> group1 = settings, group2 = null, group3 = null, group4 = null
settings/205                            // should be matched to --> group1 = settings, group2 = null, group3 = null, group4 = 205

settings/notifications                  // should be matched to --> group1 = settings, group2 = notifications, group3 = null, group4 = null
settings/notifications/                 // should be matched to --> group1 = settings, group2 = notifications, group3 = null, group4 = null
settings/notifications/50               // should be matched to --> group1 = settings, group2 = notifications, group3 = null, group4 = 50

settings/notifications/pingers          // should be matched to --> group1 = settings, group2 = notifications, group3 = pingers, group4 = null
settings/notifications/pingers/         // should be matched to --> group1 = settings, group2 = notifications, group3 = pingers, group4 = null
settings/notifications/pingers/101      // should be matched to --> group1 = settings, group2 = notifications, group3 = pingers, group4 = 101
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where is the regex you tried already and what exactly didn't work about it?

Comment: As most "please give teh codez" questions, this is offtopic for being too broad. Please take the [tour], especially [ask].

Comment: Wouldn't it be a LOT easier to split on `/` and `?`?

Comment: No, b/c I need to populate all these 4 groups and if i split it i would need to loop through the array and that is costly.

Answer (score 0):

You can `string#split` on `/` and test if the last word to be digit and empty string and create your object using destructuring.

```js
var arr = ['settings', 'settings/','settings/205','settings/notifications','settings/notifications/', 'settings/notifications/50','settings/notifications/pingers','settings/notifications/pingers/','settings/notifications/pingers/101']

var result = arr.map(url => {
  var words = url.split('/');
  var last = null;
  
  if(/\d+/g.test(words[words.length - 1]))
      last = words.pop();
  else if(!words[words.length - 1] || /\s+/g.test(words[words.length - 1]))
    words.pop();
  
  var [group1, group2=null, group3=null] = [...words];
  var group4 = last;
  return {group1, group2, group3, group4};
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! Firstly, I do not want to use map or any other iteration techniques b/c that is too costly. Secondly, I might use this with a server-side language ( not node ) and things like destructuring and spread cannot be used. So i am really looking for a mathing pattern

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code in perl. The pattern itself will work everywhere.

```
$string  = "settings/notifications/pingers/101";
#$string  = "settings/notifications/pingers";
#$string  = "settings/notifications";
#$string  = "settings";

$string  =~  m/^(\w+)(?:\/)?(\w+)?(?:\/)?(\w+)?(?:\/)?(\d+)?$/;

print $1."\n"; 
print $2."\n"; 
print $3."\n"; 
print $4."\n";
```